# Push the next view controller after a delay?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I'm trying to push the next view controller after a delay, using a timer.
I already made an app with an one second timer, but I'd like it to stop after a period of time.

```
import UIKit

class Level1: UIViewController {    

    var timerCount = 0
    var timmerRunning = false
    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    func Counting() {
        timerCount += 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if !timmerRunning {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timmerRunning = true
        }        
    }

    @IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if timmerRunning {
            timer.invalidate()
            timmerRunning = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func restartButton(sender: UIButton) {        
        timerCount = 0
        timerLabel.text = "0"        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your *timerCount* variable in the *counting* function like that and after it has reached your desired period of time, stop the timer and present the new ViewController:

```
func Counting() {
  timerCount += 1
  timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
  if timerCount == desiredPeriodOfTime {
     self.timer.invalidate()
     self.timmerRunning = false
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        let viewController = NewViewController()
        self.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but there is no need to dispatch_async to main queue, because Counting method is called on main queue.

Comment: Thank you, but when I want to run this, it shows me: Cannot convert value of type ´LevelSucess.Type´, Type´to expected argument type´UIViewController´.

Comment: You have to replace 'NewViewController' with your ViewController class, you want to present.